# Redirect htaccess Based On Partial Folder Name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a set of dated folders I want to move into one container folder. That is

20011104
20011008

will now be in

archive/20011104
archive/20011104

is there any way to htaccess redirect these in a few lines, rather than one redirect for each. There are hundreds. Is it possible to do a wildcard like 200* such that all such requests get redirected into the archive folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you know it will start with 200, and will be 8 digits long, you should be able to match with this:

```
RewriteRule    (200\d{5})$              /archive/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Edit**: I'm assuming you're using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)